# Basic knowledge of backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to backbone.js. Could anyone please tell me the meaning of `<%= done ? 'checked="checked"' : '' %>` in the below code?

```
<div class="view">
  <input class="toggle" type="checkbox" <%= done ? 'checked="checked"' : '' %> />
  <label><%- title %></label>
  <a class="destroy"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: i know the internal part is of conditional operator. but what is mean by <%=  %>

Comment: Its a templating language - what else are you using other than backbone ?

Comment: And John Resigs templating engine by the looks of it - read the docs here -> http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is used to the convert HTML for pure js code.
Its a Embedding scripts in your page that have a unknown content-type which are simply ignored by the browser and by search engines.

Example :

```
<% if (done) { %>
<a id="clear-completed">Clear <%= done %> completed 
<%= done == 1 ? 'item' : 'items'    %></a>
<% } %>
<div class="todo-count"><b><%= remaining %></b> 
<%= remaining == 1 ? 'item' : 'items' %>   left</div>
</script>
```

For knowledge:
 http://backbonetutorials.com/

http://backbonejs.org/

http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

Study the below tutorials for more reference:
Src code to check for git hub :

https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone